# nodejs parsing requested query to text

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am new to nodejs, so maybe this is a stupid question.

I am working with the real-time engine socket.io in nodejs to have a real time connection between my mysql server and a front-end webpage.

the purpose of my setup is to make a value of mysql server appear on the index page. The problem is that, the value is not the value that i want. It's showing me "[object Object]" and its need to be a number.

my apologies for the bad english.
hopefully someone can help me.

My setup.

this the server file "Server.js"

```
var app = require('express')();  
var server = require('http').Server(app);  
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host : 'localhost',
user : 'root',
password : 'toor',
database: "smatool"
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.listen(8080);  

io.on("connection", function (socket) { 

//send data to client
var interval = setInterval(function(){

    connection.query("SELECT Value FROM `LiveData` WHERE Description = 'Total Power' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1",  function(err, rows){
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            socket.emit('announcement', {message: rows});
            console.log( rows );
        }
    });

}, 1000);
socket.on("disconnect", function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
});
```

this is the html file index.html

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <script>
     var socket = io.connect();
     socket.on('announcement', function(data){
        $('#date').text(data.message);
     });
     </script>
     <div id="date"></div>
     <textarea id="text"></textarea>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: as far as I can tell from the documentation of the mysql module you're using (https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), **rows** is an array of `objects` containing all the rows returned, hence you should loop it, because **data.message**, received by the client, is an array of object, and you probably want to either loop it or print its first element(`data.message[0]`). To have a clear idea of what is happening, anyway, I suggest you to `console.log(data);` on your client and to check what you are currently receiving on the console.

Comment: The output of console.log(data.message[0]); was undifined. Don't know why, because like you said this is the first element of the array. and if i do console.log(data); i get the same result as on the index page "Object { message: Object }".

Comment: Okay, so it means that `data.message` is an object, try to `console.log(data.message);` instead and check what it prints in the console :)

Comment: Ok, i get some good results. Object { Value: 1325 }. strange that the console "can" display the value and the index page not?

Comment: do i maybe need to parse it to a string to give the value ?

Comment: No you don't need to "parse" it, you just need to echo it properly. You're trying to echo an object, hence it is being parsed as [Object object], you are **supposed** to either return an object and retrieve a value from it (in this case data.message.Value) or return the value directly. If you didn't **yet** understand objects in javascript, I highly suggest you to read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects **before** moving on with your project.

Comment: Ok, will do. Anyway thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are returning rows, which is an array instead of rows[0].column_name within the emit socket command. See https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#introduction as an example.

Comment: Was thinking the same, but if i do like you said. "$('#date').text(data.message[0].Value);" i get in the console undefined object.

Comment: So, the are you getting Object {Value: 1325} in the Server.js console.log? If so, what happens if you:  

Server.js:  

    socket.emit('announcement', {message: rows[0].Value});  
    console.log( rows[0].Value );

Comment: finly getting some good results. so i changed  socket.emit('announcement', {message: rows}); into socket.emit('announcement', {message: rows[0].Value}); and the wanted value is presenting on the index page. thank you very much.

Comment: Sure, that would be great. I added a note to the solution "within the emit socket command" to be more specific.